# Gridview Flutter - wide gaps

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, layout

I have the following code for an admin page where he/she can toggle permissions for other users
Here is the code for the Gridview I have, however, there are substantial white gaps between the grid view elements.

I think the problem is from the setHeight(context, 0.88) which takes 88% of the screen size for each part of the gridview idk

I can't seem to figure out how to fix it :(

There is an img below...note that there are repeated parts for each department ... so the Sales department has the same as accounting/finance and so on

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          primary: true,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Divider(
                color: kLightGreyColor,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: setHeight(context, 0.88), //88%
                width: setWidth(context, 0.65), //65%
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: widget.company.departments.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                      List<String> functionalities = [
                        'Manage Clients',
                        'Manage Suppliers',
                        'Manage Products',
                        'Import Data',
                        'Manage Sheets',
                        'Manage Projects'
                      ];
                      List<IconData> iconData = [
                        CSheets.customer,
                        CSheets.supplier,
                        CSheets.product,
                        CSheets.customExcel,
                        CSheets.customCostSheet,
                        Icons.build,
                      ];
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          CustomRegistrationTitle(
                              title: widget.company.departments.elementAt(i)),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: setWidth(context, 0.6),
                              child: GridView.count(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                crossAxisCount: (setWidth(context, 0.01) > 8)
                                    ? 3
                                    : (setWidth(context, 0.01) < 6)
                                        ? 1
                                        : 2,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                                children: List.generate(
                                  functionalities.length,
                                  (index) {
                                    return SizedBox(
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              AutoSizeText(
                                                functionalities
                                                    .elementAt(index),
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                                style:
                                                    kResponsiveTextOverpassFont(
                                                        context,
                                                        kDarkGreyColor),
                                              ),
                                              Transform.scale(
                                                scale: 0.7,
                                                child: CupertinoSwitch(
                                                    activeColor: kDarkBlueColor,
                                                    value:
                                                        widget.company
                                                                    .permissions[
                                                                widget.company
                                                                    .departments
                                                                    .elementAt(
                                                                        i)][
                                                            functionalities
                                                                .elementAt(
                                                                    index)],
                                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                                      setState(() {
                                                        p[widget
                                                            .company.departments
                                                            .elementAt(
                                                                i)]![functionalities
                                                            .elementAt(
                                                                index)] = value;
                                                      });
                                                      companyRef
                                                          .doc(globalCompanyId)
                                                          .update(
                                                              {'permissions': p});
                                                    }),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                top: setHeight(context, 0.03)),
                                            child: Icon(
                                              iconData.elementAt(index),
                                              size: setWidth(context, 0.03),
                                              color: kDarkGreyColor,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[image: wide gaps for gridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its from Gridview.count.
by default gridview will set the children size. for debugging you can wrap the children inside the gridview and set the color. You will see the default size of them.

```
//for debug, to see the  current size of gridview child
....
children: List.generate(
   functionalities.length,
   index) {
     return Container(
       color: Colors.amber,
       child: Column(
....
```

you will see the actual height and width.tha white gab is actually is the remaining unused size

---

to customize the size, you have to set the aspect Ratio property on gridview.

```
 GridView.count(
   //var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   // double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
   // double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
   // this value that i usually use in mobile, idk for web size. you can try by your self
   childAspectRatio: itemHeight / itemWidth,
   children: []
```

now your `gridview` children should change the size.

Comment: childAspectRatio did the trick! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

adding childAspectRatio : 1.5
to the GridView.count did the trick

the higher the ratio the smaller the gap

[image]